# State not set on button press 1st time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

`Else if` Condition not give response on 1st click button, it always give response 2nd click on button.
I'm trying get `date diff between two date`, minimum date to maximum date.

Date came every click according to selected date, but maxDate & minDate not set in state.

After 2nd click first date set in minDate, 3rd click set 2nd date as maxDate. 
But i want set date as well as click on button.

```
this.onDayPress = this.selecionarData.bind(this);

selecionarData(date){
let {year, month, day} = date;
 if (this.state.minDate && this.state.maxDate) {
      if (this.state.minDate > day) {
        this.setState({
          minDate: day
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          maxDate: day
        });
      }
    } else if (this.state.minDate && this.state.maxDate === undefined) {
      if (this.state.minDate > day) {
        this.setState({
          minDate: day,
          maxDate: this.state.minDate
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          maxDate: day
        })
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({
        minDate: day
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the initial state for `minDate` and `maxDate`.

See here for documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much to giving idea.
Actually it's work link this in my case :

```
   if (this.state.minDate > day) {
         this.setState({
             minDate: day
          },() =>{this.methodCall()});
        } else {
          this.setState({
             maxDate: day
          },() =>{this.methodCall()});
       }
   }
```